# How to deactivate toast notification in windows phone 7.5

Tags: notifications

Each time i'm getting sms i got notification on the top of the screen of the phone (i have lumia 800) Is that possible somehow to swith off or deactivate this notification? Or prevent appearence of it. Sometimes it is really bad that even mobile is locked and lying on the desk/table everybody can see from whom i got sms and what is the first sentences.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is something akin to a "do not disturb" mode. Windows Phone 7.5 doesn't currently support such a feature, nor does it have the ability to disable toast notifications for core system apps (for third-party apps, developers often build a switch to disable toasts, but it only affects their own app).

This can be a privacy concern, of course, as it does display the beginning of the text and from who it was sent. Though (correct me if I'm wrong) it is typical of smartphones. I remember seeing my friend's iPhone do something similar on the lock screen.

It might just be standard industry practice for the moment. But to answer your question, unfortunately, no, there is no way to do it.

That isn't to say that the option might exist in a modded Windows Phone 7 rom, but I don't know if such a one exists.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, Iphone have the simular feature but the same time you can shoose manually the view of notification (on the top of the screen or on the middle) or even switch it off (prevent appearence at all) Anyway i will try to approach Windows directly to find out about further implementation such 'shoose mode'

Comment: I don't think 'Do not disturb' feature which will be added in 7.8 addresses this concern. I also think android and WP lacks this security concern. One should be able to turn-off or modify the behaviour of all basic system apps. Actually the whole concept of message notification is wrong right now. Only the incoming message reporting should be done and no other info is required.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay I agree that there is a better way of doing it. I don't like that my phone displays even part of the text message even if the phone is locked. But it's something I've had to deal with. Like, if I don't want others reading them, don't leave the phone out and if I do, turn it off or silence it so no one thinks to look.